# AutoMapper - change the object reference in AfterMap

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper and after my mapping is complete I want to replace the mapped object with the object reference I have already instantiated in my app.
I have injected service to my Profile :

```
 public CustomProfile(IObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            this.objectProvider= objectProvider;               
            CreateMap<Source, Destination>().
                AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                {
                    dest = objectProvider.GetObject(src.someValue);
                });

        }
```

I know that I can do something like this:

```
 CreateMap<Source, Destination>().
                AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                {
                    var object = objectProvider.GetObject(src.someValue);
                    dest.Name = object.Name;                            
                 });
```

But I want to assing the reference of existing object, not create a new one.
If it cannot be achieved this way, could anybody explain me, why this assignment is not working?
Some lambda flavours I am not familiar with?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: I have read it but did not find the answer I am looking form

Comment: That's what you need instead of `AfterMap`.